# Using file_exists to check if image exist before echo

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm trying to let my script check if an image exist before echoing it into my table. If it doesn't exist, it should echo another image in stead. My problem is that even though the image exist, it still goes to the else factor. Can anyone spot any coding mistakes?

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("xxxx");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yyyy WHERE frivillig=1 ORDER BY stilling");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td width="50px" class="frivillig"><?php  if (file_exists($url . "ansatte" . "/" . (utf8_encode($row['etternavn'])) . "%20" . (utf8_encode($row['fornavn'])) . ".jpg")) {
echo "<img" . " " . "src='" . $url . "ansatte" . "/" . (utf8_encode($row['etternavn'])) . "%20" . (utf8_encode($row['fornavn'])) . ".jpg'" . " " . "height='50px'/>";
}
else {
echo "<img" . " " . "src='" . $url . "images/mangler.png'" . " " . "height='50px'/>";
}
?>
```

As you can see, I use $url for my complete url, and the images are placed in the /ansatte/ folder.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I spot a coding mistake. Stop using `mysql_*` functions. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the below snippet for checking remote resources:

```
$path = $url . "ansatte" . "/" . (utf8_encode($row['etternavn'])) . "%20" . (utf8_encode($row['fornavn'])) . ".jpg"

$ch = curl_init($path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode < 400) { // Filter out bad request, not found, etc
 // found
} else {
 // not accessible
}
```

If you don't have php5-curl installed, you could also look at the following alternatives:

**getimagesize**

Again only certain streams are supported here, but usage is simple and it will validate the return better:

```
if (getimagesize($path) !== FALSE) {
  //exists
}
```

**fopen**

```
if (fopen($path,"r") !== FALSE) {
  // exists
}
```

**get_headers**

```
$headers = get_headers($path, TRUE);
if ($headers !== false && isset($headers['Content-Type']) && $headers['Content-Type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
  // exists
}
```

Comment: Could also use `PECL_HTTP`, or Zend, or Pear. Anything that allows a proper HTTP Request to be sent and the response code captured.

Comment: @crush yep, `fopen` and `getimagesize` may be worthy alternatives and don't require plugins.

Comment: I would think that `fopen` would fall to the same issues as `file_exists`? At the least, it would still return a handle to an error-redirect page if the server host served them for invalid urls.

Comment: @crush yes, it would.. If he controls the configuration on the webserver it shouldn't be an issue though. Alternatively, `get_header` could be used to validate the `content-type`. I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: `get_headers()` triggers a warning if the URL is invalid or does not resolve. Might want to suppress warnings on it's invocation, since you are manually checking it afterwards.

Comment: +1, however they should be turned off in a production environment. It's fine to add a @ in this case though on development environments.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, using your get_headers alternative I got the desired outcome. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists()` isn't intended for checking URLs.  Your call to `file_exists()` should reflect a relative or absolute filesystem path instead of a URL.

Comment: From the manual: "As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers."

Comment: @Mike I was just posting that. Here's a list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: @Mike "can also be" doesn't mean "should be".  Is `file_exists()` smart enough to detect a 404 error, or would it return false only if the webserver didn't respond at all?

Comment: @Mike After testing it using PHP 5.3.20, I can tell you that even if a file *does* exist using an http URL, the function appears to return false.  So `file_exists()` is probably an inappropriate function to use for the poster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a hunch here and assuming that the image file is, in fact, on the same server as the script. If so, you should be using absolute or relative paths when checking if the file exists, not a URL.

```
<?php

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM yyyy WHERE frivillig=1 ORDER BY stilling");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/subdir/';
$path = '/path/to/yoursite/subdir/';

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td width="50px" class="frivillig">
    <?php
    if (file_exists($path . "ansatte" . "/" . (utf8_encode($row['etternavn'])) . "%20" . (utf8_encode($row['fornavn'])) . ".jpg")) {
        echo "<img" . " " . "src='" . $url . "ansatte" . "/" . (utf8_encode($row['etternavn'])) . "%20" . (utf8_encode($row['fornavn'])) . ".jpg'" . " " . "height='50px'/>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<img" . " " . "src='" . $url . "images/mangler.png'" . " " . "height='50px'/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Also as @crush mentioned, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated as of PHP 5.5. The above example uses PDO.